# How to prevent github copilot from reading .env files?

Tags: pycharm, github-copilot, .env

I am using PyCharm and GitHub Copilot with it and want to prevent Copilot from reading the .env file with api tokens.

I noticed there is an option to **“disable completion for textmate”**. However, I am unsure if this option only disables the auto-completion feature or if it also prevents GitHub Copilot from reading my .env files. Could anyone clarify what exactly the **“disable completion for textmate”** option does and suggest any additional steps I might need to take to prevent GitHub Copilot from accessing my .env files?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way as log you use GitHub Copilot / ChatGPT extension in Pycharm or any other editor  (eg. VS Code) because they access your files too not only your input for suggestion ..
Stay safe : Disable autosuggestion if possible
Anyway Github share data breach info to company using such data.